# C: Sort Comma Delimited List of Numbers in a file

Tags: c

I need to sort a list of numbers in a file in a ascending order. I have done all the opening of the file and created my bubble sort function. But I'm stuck on how to make this all work together.

`my inputefile.csv` looks something like the following:

```
3,-4,-5,-8
10,30,50,-10
40,100,60,-2

void bubble_sort(char* line, int size);

int main(void)
{
  FILE *file;
  char* line;
  int size = sizeof(line);

  file = fopen("inputfile.csv", "r");
  if(file == NULL)
  {
    printf("Unable to open the file");
  }else
      {
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)
        {
          bubble_sort(line, size)  
        }
      }
}

void bubble_sort(char* line, int size)
{
  int temp, i, j;

  for (i=0; i< size-1; i++)
  {
    for (j=0; j<size-1; j++)
    {
      if(line[j] > line[j+1])
       {
         temp = line[j];
         line[j] = line[j+1];
         line[j+1] = temp;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The number of lines is unknown and also each line has 4 integers separated by a comma. By my code you could say i am a newbee

Comment: What do you expect from `file[j]`? Edit: your function call or the funtion declaration is wrong. `bubble_sort(line, size)`, with `char *, int` vs. `void bubble_sort(FILE *file, size)`. Also `size` has no type.

Comment: You've allocated no memory for `line`, and reading `sizeof(char *)` from the file isn't what you really intend to do. There are dozens of posts here about reading lines of text from a file (see the related list to the right ====>>>>). Start there. You have to be able to read the line before you start to worry about parsing it, and you have to parse it before you can sort the content. You've managed neither of those yet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  It is good to show your input data; it is better to show your expected output too.  Are you sorting the data on each line numerically, or are you sorting the lines into numeric order, with ties in the first field sorting on the second field, etc?  It looks like you're supposed to be sorting each line individually.  Your code does not split the line up into numeric fields, so it will not work.  You need to split the line into an array of numbers, sort the numbers, and then regenerate the line for output.

Comment: I'm sorting the data on each line numerically

Comment: No, you are incorrectly sorting (due to sizes on your arrays) each individual character passed into bubble_sort - including commas and negative signs.  You need to convert the data coming in from characters to actual integers (and remove the commas) before you can sort it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void bubble_sort(int *array, int size);

int main(void){
    FILE *file;
    char line[128];

    if((file = fopen("inputfile.csv", "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Unable to open the file");
        return -1;
    }
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)){
        int i, a[4], size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);
        sscanf(line, "%d,%d,%d,%d", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3]);
        bubble_sort(a, size);
        for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            printf("%d", a[i]);
            if(i<size-1)
                printf(", ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

void bubble_sort(int *a, int size){
    int i, temp, swap;

    do{
        for(swap=i=0;i<size-1;++i){
            if(a[i]>a[i+1]){
                swap = 1;
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
        --size;
    }while(swap);
}
```